# gnuplot multiplot images in column

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to use multiplot to stack two image plots on top of one another, in a column. When I try to test this with x11 terminal, the images are produced separately, only one visible at a time. When I use the epslatex terminal, which is what I want, then the text is drawn correctly within the LaTeX document, but the EPS portion of the plot is produced as two separate pages, resulting in a figure that is missing a lower half.

Here's the multiplot section of my script:

```
set multiplot 2,1

set cbrange [-0.4:0.4]
set cbtics -0.4,0.2,0.4
unset xlabel
set tmargin at screen 0.95
set bmargin at screen 0.60
plot data u 1:2:3 with image notitle

set cbrange [-0.1:0.1]
set cbtics -0.1,0.05,0.1
set xlabel "$x$"
set tmargin at screen 0.50
set bmargin at screen 0.15
plot data u 1:2:3 with image notitle

unset multiplot
unset output
```

What results in the document is this:

[image: multiplot-image]

I have tried enlarging the vertical size of the plotting area[(per this question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863194/vertically-stacked-multiplot-in-gnuplot), but what this does is increase size of each page in the EPS file. To be clear, the product of plotting with epslatex is an EPS file containing two pages, the first with the first plot at the position that I want (near the top), and the second with the second plot at the position that I want (near the bottom).

Comment: Are you sure that you are in multiplot mode? The command `set multiplot 2,1` does not work for me (`set multiplot layout 2,1` works), and I can reproduce the behavior described by removing the `multiplot` commands completely.

Comment: @maij, that did it. It was as silly syntax error. Thanks.

If you propose the solution, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This normally happens when you are not in multiplot mode. For me, `set multiplot 2,1` gives an error message "only valid in the context of an auto-layout command". The command `set multiplot layout 2,1` works with Gnuplot 5.0 and 4.6.

As a side note: This behavior can be used to produce animated gifs with `set terminal gif animate`, each `plot` command creates a new frame.